Browser doesn't save cookie
I'm using Go Fiber and it's session middleware for a simple authentication system.
Every thing is working except that the browser doesn't save the cookie.
my backend is served on https://127.0.0.1:3033 and my frontend is on https://127.0.0.1:4321
this the cookie sent by server :
session_id=7bbb86ac-04e7-43b2-8f0a-345d720efa35; max-age=900; domain=127.0.0.1; path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None
This is my Fiber Session config :
func initSessionStore() *session.Store {
    store := session.New(session.Config{
        CookieHTTPOnly: true,
        Expiration:     time.Minute * 15,
        Storage:        sqlite3.New(),
        CookieSecure:   false,
        CookieSameSite: "None",
        CookieDomain:   "127.0.0.1",
        CookiePath:     "/",
    })
    return store
}


This my cors config:
cors.New(cors.Config{
            AllowOrigins:     os.Getenv("FRONTEND_URL"), // 127.0.0.1:4321 
            AllowCredentials: true,
        }),

What I've already tried:

serving my apps on Https
using fake domains (subdomain for backend)
trying different browsers


How are you calling the backend from the frontend?

What is the purpose of setting the CookieDomain to 127.0.0.1 instead of just leaving it empty? Also, your code says "CookieSecure: false" yet the cookie shows "secure". So the code seems to contradict the result, is it really from the same run? Also, how did you determine that the browser does not safe the cookie?


"secure": You must use https, even on localhost. 2. Domain name cookies on IP addresses kinda work but are a totally nonsensical idea, don't do that.


@Evert this is how i'm calling the api :
fetch("https://127.0.0.1:3033/auth/users/user-info" , {credentials:"include",  })



I am using https on my localhost @volker

When you use Domains the cookie will be secured,
I was just messing around with options that's why I'm using Domain. @SteffenUllrich

@Volker https being required for localhost is outdated information. This used to be true, but localhosti s now considered a secure context.

I agree with Amirreza, remove the domain. After this cookie is set, where do you expect it to show up/ A cookie set on your backend origin will not show up on your frontend origin, but it should be sent with any subsequent requests to the backend

So finally I found out why this didn't work.
I forgot to use credentials:"include" where the OAuth was landing in the front end, I can't believe I have forgotten that ...
